Databricks Autoloader long initialization
We use the Autoloader pattern in Databricks to fill from raw files in our storage account into Delta tables. Though successfull for almost all tables, for 2 tables we face strange behaviour.
It takes always more than an hour to initiate the streaming, as seen in bottom of this image. All other tables are filled in under 5 minutes each. 
Looking into the cluster, it seems that the nodes are inactive. There are no active jobs listed. 
The only activity I can find are in the logs below, where GC is active. I already looked into this SO article that tells that this are 'normal' processes. But I would like to know how I can prevent this behaviour, since the delay hinders our operations. Moreover, other tables don't have any issues in being filled with streaming job.
2024-10-01T13:10:58.020+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 2598464K->8576K(2641920K)] 3753444K->1163556K(8001024K), 0.0190420 secs] [Times: user=0.12 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs] 
2024-10-01T13:12:01.428+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 2610560K->11712K(2639360K)] 3765540K->1166700K(7998464K), 0.0230643 secs] [Times: user=0.13 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs] 
2024-10-01T13:13:04.829+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 2613696K->9440K(2646528K)] 3768684K->1165483K(8005632K), 0.0209397 secs] [Times: user=0.12 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs] 
2024-10-01T13:14:08.485+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 2620640K->8164K(2643968K)] 3776683K->1164544K(8003072K), 0.0198620 secs] [Times: user=0.12 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs] 
2024-10-01T13:15:11.601+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 2619364K->7921K(2650112K)] 3775744K->1164596K(8009216K), 0.0240125 secs] [Times: user=0.13 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs] 
2024-10-01T13:16:16.373+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 2627313K->7712K(2648576K)] 3783988K->1164827K(8007680K), 0.0202102 secs] [Times: user=0.11 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs] 
2024-10-01T13:17:19.317+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 2627104K->10816K(2653184K)] 3784219K->1168242K(8012288K), 0.0224084 secs] [Times: user=0.11 sys=0.00, real=0.03 secs] 
2024-10-01T13:18:22.487+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 2636864K->9280K(2652160K)] 3794290K->1167026K(8011264K), 0.0208604 secs] [Times: user=0.11 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs] 

TLDR:
Long initiation for Autoloader stream. How to prevent?

Are you using Directory Listing or File Notification?
How many files are there in those two folders?

Hi Ganesh, files arrive daily since 2016, so 3000 files are in the folder, each of 230MiB approximately. For other kind of data we have similar sized folders, but these are not affected by the high initialization.
